# Apps deployed on Heroku do not reflect on a part of programme although they can work on local server

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

**This application was developed through Djangogirls tutorial (https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/).

I would like to know how to find out the reason and fix them. I dont get why those kinds of problems happens as the blow pictures show.**

---

The local server: Everything does work correctly and I just would like to make this work on heroku
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h18tv.png)

Apps deployed on Heroku: Any post does not show up although I think that I push correctly files on heroku 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHIOT.png)

---

> What I already did was here:
>  1) restart heroku and relaunch
>   apps
>  2) clear cache of chrome and reload apps
>  3) check git
>   log
>  4) commit and push again (git push heroku master)
>
> What should I do next ? 
>  See how data migration is working but I
>   do not know how to check ...

ーーUPDATE 20180314
I do not think that the code has something wrong because it correctly works on local server.
 Data (=posts) come from posgresql on heroku while local server uses sqlite3.The data is stored on database by translating into SQL over migration files which is kind of intermediate files.

The below tree is the structure of this application.

```
blog
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models.py
├── templates
│   └── blog
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── post_detail.html
│       ├── post_edit.html
│       └── post_list.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

The source files on the above pics might be relevant to the two below files. (1) base.html (2) post_list.html

(1) base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Girls blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
<a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(2) post_list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

ーーUPDATE20180315
I checked the differences between data in local server and heroku.
The data seems to be different somehow but Im not sure of how to resolve it.

1) local server

```
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Post: Sample title>, <Post: Sample title1>, <Post: Sample title2>, <Post: Sample title3>]>
>>>
```

2) heroku

```
djgpractice::DATABASE=> select*from blog_post;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------------------------------
id             | 1
title          | test
text           | test
created_date   | 2018-03-13 15:04:57+00
published_date | 
author_id      | 1
-[ RECORD 2 ]--+------------------------------
id             | 2
title          | test
text           | test
created_date   | 2018-03-13 15:22:31.942797+00
published_date | 
author_id      | 1
-[ RECORD 3 ]--+------------------------------
id             | 3
title          | test
text           | test
created_date   | 2018-03-13 15:54:34.933753+00
published_date | 
author_id      | 1
```

This is the database list on heroku

```
djgpractice::DATABASE-> \d
                           List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   |     Owner      
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------------
 public | auth_group                        | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_group_id_seq                 | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_group_permissions            | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_group_permissions_id_seq     | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_permission                   | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_permission_id_seq            | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user                         | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user_groups                  | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user_groups_id_seq           | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user_id_seq                  | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user_user_permissions        | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | auth_user_user_permissions_id_seq | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | blog_post                         | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | blog_post_id_seq                  | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_admin_log                  | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_admin_log_id_seq           | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_content_type               | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_content_type_id_seq        | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_migrations                 | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_migrations_id_seq          | sequence | tcdjrkyztekdbd
 public | django_session                    | table    | tcdjrkyztekdbd
(21 rows)
```

Comment: Firstly, images of issues aren't super helpful (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). That said, the different seems to be that "Sample Title" (and some other stuff) is shown on one site, but not the other. Can you show us the code and/or templates that show that data on the page? Does it come from DB data?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the URL. I added more information about the issue on the above post. I would be grad if you gave me the points or files which I should check next because I'm still stuck.

Comment: Are you certain there is data in the DB on heroku?

Comment: There was data in the DB on heroku but it seems to be different. So the problem might come from the process of deploying or migrating data from local server to heroku. So should I overwrite or migrate next ? I'm curious of why those happened though.